# How to resize a Bitmap Image and set it as the backgroound of a grid in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, grid, bitmapimage

I tried doing this but I can't figure out how to set the height and width of the `ImageBrush` before setting it as the background of the grid.

```
BitmapImage bmp= new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath, UriKind.Relative));
int height = bmp.DecodePixelHeight;
int width = bmp.DecodePixelWidth;

ImageBrush imgBrush = new ImageBrush();
imgBrush.ImageSource = bmp;
MainGrid.Background = imgBrush    // MainGrid is the name of the Grid
```

Answer (score -1):

If you simply want to set the imageBrush to fill the gird properly set the stretch property of the imageBrush to either uniform (maintains proportions but may leave empty spots) or uniform to fill (maintains proportions, does not leave empty spots, but whole picture may not fit in grid).

Otherwise there is more complex code here to set the exact pixel width and height of an imageBrush.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742114.aspx